# How to make validation on Put httpmethods?

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa

I am getting stuck to make validation on my put/update services

```
 public Book updateBook (Book book){
        Book existingbook = repository.findById(book.getId()).orElse(null);
        existingbook.setQuantity(book.getQuantity());
        existingbook.setName(book.getName());
        existingbook.setPrice(book.getPrice());
        return repository.save(existingbook);
    }
```

How to make validation when the user only can set a quantity lower than 100?

Answer (score 0):

You should use validation from `javax.validation` package.

- [Java Bean Validation Basics](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation)
- [Validating Form Input](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/)
- [Spring MVC Custom Validation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator)